# Could the Planeteers switch rings?

Tags: captain-planet

Or for that matter, utilise more than one ring at a time?

Obviously each character was chosen for a particular power - and after a while would've built up experience using their ring - and Gaia probably didn't want one or two people to hold all the power. But in some sort of emergency situation surely they could use each other's powers and/or hold two or more rings at once.

I'm imagining two scenarios:

- One of the Planeteers is unconscious, and the others need him/her to use their power to summon Ol' Captain Planet
- The rings are taken off them by the enemy. Due to the heavy amount of Plotinium in the air, the Planeteers get a chance to take them back, and just pick up whatever ring is closest at hand and wave it wildly in the direction of the bad guys.

Were these ever valid scenarios? or did the rings only work with the specific Planeteer?

Comment: Given the length of the series, I'd be surprised something like Scenario 2 didn't actually happen in at least one episode...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### **Short Answer:**

**No, each ring was linked specifically to each user. They were unable to switch rings or control each other elemental aspects. Nor were there any episodes where ring switching ever took place (however rings were stolen from the heroes several times over the run of the series.)**

### **Long Answer:**

The very premise sets up the show indicating each hero was aligned with a particular element and mindset. Each was linked with their ring and their power was unavailable to anyone else.

**From the introduction to the show:**

"Our world is in peril. Gaia, the spirit of the Earth, can no longer withstand the destruction plaguing our planet. She sends five rings to five special young people:

- Kwame, from Africa, with the power of Earth...
- From North America, Wheeler, with the power of Fire...
- From The Soviet Union , Linka, with the power of Wind.
- From Asia, Gi, with the power of Water...
- and from South America, Ma-Ti with the power of Heart.
- With the five powers combined they summon Earth's greatest champion, Captain Planet."

Each Planeteer was linked to their element by their temperament and as strange as it sounds if one of them was to be absent or removed from the Time stream as when Wheeler refuses the call from Gaia in the episodes "Two Futures, Part One and Part Two" it caused an entire collapse of the story universe as if there was no other person who could have taken Wheeler's place as the wielder of the Ring of Fire.

- I consider it a morality tale seeing how Gaia claims that this group are the "first Planeteers", but in later episodes, such as Hog Tide, she tells the Planeteers stories of earlier generations having served the Earth in the same way, with the same powers.

Gaia indicates that without Wheeler's intervention, the rest of the Planeteer's did not continue and stopped working together. Granted this smacks of a morality tale where Gaia gives Wheeler the option of going back through time and correcting his mistake but it certainly appeared there was no one else who could use the Ring of Fire in his absence.

### **Production Notes**

This was a children's show aimed at a very young demographic. Most of its themes were light-hearted and in keeping with cartoons of the period. It produced 6 seasons and over one hundred episodes. As such:

- The show was kept very simple, with simple themes, simple ideas and very comic villains. Each hero was strongly associated with their ring, so the idea of switching them was probably never going to happen often, if at all.
- The ring wielders NEVER used the full range of abilities capable in their rings. If they did, Captain Planet would never have to be summoned. Only in one episode did Ma-Ti use his mind control powers to the fullest extent to dominate and control people with it (Two Futures, Part One and Part Two).
- I suspect part of the show's guidelines included keeping the rings under-performing so Captain Planet could make his appearance and give his sermon about protecting the environment.

Comment: Very good answer. However it is worth mentioning that unlike most children's shows of the same era, this one features a ridiculous [all-star cast](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098763/fullcredits) and is very well written. In fact, I'd love to see a reboot for the current generation. Seriously; Meg Ryan, Tim Curry, Ed Asner, Sting, Malcolm McDowell, the list goes on.

Comment: You are right DampeS8N, there was an amazing list of star talents who did voices on the show. It was a product very well loved during its time. I would like to see it redone but I am not even sure how you would approach it today. Kids today are very different and probably wouldn't react the same way... Business probably would not support it either since we have a much less friendly view of the environment today. Today's business leaders resemble the villains of the Captain Planet series...

Comment: In one episode they all (other than Ma-Ti) replace their rings with gloves of power which are much more powerful. They then use these gloves to go on a mission to take by force the nuclear weapons from the USA and USSR nearly triggering a thermonuclear war. It is not shown if other people could have wielded the gloves other than the planeteers, which would be similar to ring-swapping.

Comment: @DampeS8N Holy crap... LeVar Burton was Kwame?!

Comment: @DampeS8N - Haha of course Whoopi Goldberg is Gaia, it makes sense because Morgan Freeman is God :D. And I'd love to see a reboot movie as well... something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PirI19qzQoU). Too bad it's only fan-made

Comment: @Iszi LeVar ended up getting revenge on Asner in the end. haha, Roots reference.

Answer (score 1):

There was another episode in which which Captain Planet was unsummoned, and due to the fact that some of the Planeteers were in outer space (and Captain Planet's powers being limited to earth), he was still summoned with only the powers that he essentially couldn't return, making him a weaker version of himself.

I always assumed that the rings were like the rings of the Green Lantern, and work in the same principle. I guess, theoretically, less than five *could* summon Captain Planet, but that probably wouldn't be a worthwhile scenario. Also, the show's rhetoric was about people helping the planet and themselves, so they wanted to send a message that each of us had to work together via teamwork. That message would be rather defunct if just one of them could do it all themselves.

Answer (score -2):

If I remember correctly in one episode Wheeler was able to summon Captain Planet by himself basically except to statues that held the same rings the planeteer a held one statue was a Elephant that held the rings of Earth, Fire, Wind, and Water while another statute that was a rat held the ring of Heart and you only found this out at the end of the episode but I can't remember what episode it was but I think it was in season 6.

Comment: Please add punctuation, your answer is not readable.